# Accessing an host_vector item (thrust library) allocated with the pinned_allocator

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

I have the following vector:

```
thrust::host_vector< T , thrust::cuda::experimental::pinned_allocator< T > > h_vector
```

where T, in my current case, is of type `float`. I would like to access the i-th element in a correct fashion from the thrust point of view.

The naïve approach was:

```
float el = h_vector[i];
```

which resulted in the following error:

```
../src/gpu.cuh(134): error: a reference of type "float &" (not const-qualified) cannot be initialized with a value of type "thrust::host_vector<float, thrust::system::cuda::experimental::pinned_allocator<float>>"
```

Apparently, the h_array[i] type is `reference`, so i went on trying to use `thrust::raw_refence_cast` and `thrust::pointer` to retrieve my float data to no avail.

In the end, i came up with:

```
    float *raw = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(h_array->data());
    float el = raw[i];
```

Is there a better way to accomplish this?

**EDIT**: prototype code

```
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/system/cuda/experimental/pinned_allocator.h>

static const int DATA_SIZE = 1024;

int main()
{

    thrust::host_vector<float, thrust::cuda::experimental::pinned_allocator<float> > *hh = new thrust::host_vector<float, thrust::cuda::experimental::pinned_allocator<float> >(DATA_SIZE);
    float member, *fptr;
    int i;

//  member = hh[1]; //fails

    fptr = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(hh->data()); //works
    member = fptr[1];
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT 2**: 
I actually used the vector as this one:

```
thrust::host_vector< T , thrust::cuda::experimental::pinned_allocator< T > > *h_vector
```

rendering my original question completely misleading.

Comment: what is `h_array` ?  The name of your vector is `h_vector`.    I think the problem is not as you are describing it here, and you should provide a *complete*, simple reproducer, along with version details of thrust, cuda, and host compiler that you are using (which is what SO expects).   I tried to create a simple reproducer based on what you're showing and had no problems with it.  Take a look [here](http://pastebin.com/iRKKF1YX).  Please provide a complete reproducer along the lines of the example I have shown, including the complete compiler error output.

Comment: Thanks for pointing the type error out. I just added a small test case which reproduces my error. 

Note that, although in the piece provided i declared as a pointer to the host_vector and used new, the original code is a template class which should have the **host_vector** as a member.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you need this level of complication in your code.  Did you look at the example I posted [here](http://pastebin.com/iRKKF1YX)?

Anyway, this line of code:

```
   thrust::host_vector<float, thrust::cuda::experimental::pinned_allocator<float> > *hh = new thrust::host_vector<float, thrust::cuda::experimental::pinned_allocator<float> >(DATA_SIZE);
```

creates a *pointer to vector*.  That is not the same thing as a vector.

Using a construct like this:

```
member = hh[1];
```

when `hh` is a *pointer to a vector* is not a valid way of attempting to access an element in the vector.  This would be a valid way of indexing into an array of vectors, which is not what you are trying to do.

If you do this on the other hand:

```
member = (*hh)[1];
```

I believe your compile error will go away.  It does for me.

Note that I don't think this is a CUDA or thrust issue.  I run into similar trouble trying your approach with `std::vector`.  Also note that nowhere in your original question did you indicate that `h_vector` was a pointer to a vector, and the line of code that you did show did not create it that way.  So your edited/prototype code differs markedly from your original description.

Comment: You are right! I totally missed the *. I took the first excerpt from a typedef and fogot to reproduce exactly how i used. My apologies for misleading you and thank you very much for you help!